# Right way to use apache httpclient - CloseableHttpClient

Tags: httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpclient-5.x

I have below implementation of Apache http client and Implementation Class. Do we need to close the client after every request or Close the response object? Our application processes lot of API requests per second and I don't want to close and create connection for every request

HttpUtil.java

```
private static final CloseableHttpClient httpClient;
static {        
        RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
                .setSocketTimeout(TIMEOUT_SECONDS * 1000)
                .setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT_SECONDS * 1000)
                .build();
        httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setMaxConnPerRoute(20).setMaxConnTotal(500).setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).build();
    }
```

ImplementationClass.java

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpUtil.getHttpClient();
CloseableHttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
EntityUtils.consume(resp.getEntity());
```